# Toll-free bridging and memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

My iPhone app needs to do some URL escape sequence encoding for a form parameter. The NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding as stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding doesn't escape a lot.  This is what I have

```
-(NSString*)currentMessageUrlEncoded{
  CFStringRef originalURLString = (CFStringRef) self.currentMessage;
  CFStringRef urlString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, originalURLString, NULL, (CFStringRef) @"&+", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);  
  NSString *result =  (NSString*) urlString;
  [result autorelease]; // Is this sufficient?
  return result;
}
```

I'm not sure about the memory management here?  Is the autorelease on the result sufficient, or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes it is](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CarbonCocoaDoc/Articles/InterchangeableDataTypes.html). You could even shorten you method a bit:

```
- (NSString *)urlEncodedMessage:(NSString *)message {
    CFStringRef urlString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef) message, NULL, (CFStringRef) @"&+", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);  
    return [(NSString *)urlString autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link.  

(The original method was shorter, btw; I expanded it to emphasise the part about which I was asking).